# Intellisense Errors with Boost library. VS 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, intellisense

I am currently using the latest version of the Boost library. I have everything referenced as it should. However, when I built the Intellisense database, I got 99+ errors as reported by IntelliSense. Now, I know that the Boost library is popular, so I do not believe there are this many errors. Even though Intellisense reports these errors, the project builds fine. Also, I lose any use of Intellisense, such as variable prediction, in my main project.

Now, when I remove the include directory for Boost, all of my Intellisense functions come back (but as a result, I am unable to build the project).

I have tried as much as I can. I have removed the .vs folder to rebuild the database, added the directory listing in other locations, and I have gone under tools->options->search for database->C++-?Advanced set the flag to rebuild the database to true. All of this did not work.

For those wondering, these are the errors that I am getting from Intellisense

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    717 
Error (active)  E2996   There are too many errors for the IntelliSense engine to function properly, some of which may not be visible in the editor. SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\SWGMainObject.cpp  1   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    70  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    80  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    80  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    81  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    81  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    82  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    82  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    83  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    83  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    84  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    84  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    85  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    85  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    86  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    86  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    87  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    87  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    88  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    88  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    90  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    90  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    91  
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::Integer"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    91  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    97  
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    104 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::SignedInteger" SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    104 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    105 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::SignedInteger" SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    105 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    106 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::SignedInteger" SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    106 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    107 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::SignedInteger" SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    107 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    109 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::SignedInteger" SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    109 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    114 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    122 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::UnsignedInteger"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    122 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    123 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::UnsignedInteger"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    123 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    124 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::UnsignedInteger"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    124 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    125 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::UnsignedInteger"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    125 
Error (active)  E0254   type name is not allowed    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    127 
Error (active)  E0442   too few arguments for class template "boost::UnsignedInteger"   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    127 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    135 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    143 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    165 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    184 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    206 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    231 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    241 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    251 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    283 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    284 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    285 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    286 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    287 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    288 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    290 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    291 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    292 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    293 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    294 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    299 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    319 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    349 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    379 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    398 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    418 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    443 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    454 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    467 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    487 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    493 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    502 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    526 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    540 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    558 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    568 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    585 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    597 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    622 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    638 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    668 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    692 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    704 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    743 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    762 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    788 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    810 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    849 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    862 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    883 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_" is undefined   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\Boost\concept_check.hpp    925 
Error (active)  E2998   PCH warning: an unknown error occurred.  An IntelliSense PCH file was not generated.    SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\SWGMainObject.cpp  1   
Error   C2065   'target': undeclared identifier SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\SWGMainObject.cpp  19  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before 'if'   SWGModelExporter    C:\Users\user\source\repos\philm001\SWGModelExporter\SWGMainObject.cpp  20
```

I am basically at the end of my ideas on what I can do. Has anyone ran into this issue the Intellisense and the Boost library? How can I fix my Intellisense so that it can play nicely with the Boost library.

Also, I am using the precompiled installer for the Boost library.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that works for me. You need to set the preprocessor conformance mode. If anyone else is having this issue, please follow this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-preprocessor?view=msvc-170

Comment: Even though it's a compiler option, I can confirm that it works. 

Upgrading to VS 17.5.3 also fixes the problem. This was a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IntelliSens-reports-many-errors-for-the-/10287480) which was fixed in 17.5.2
Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: Yes, Upgrading to VS 17.5.3 fixed it for me as well. I was beating my head around these errors for weeks, and wasn't sure what's going on

Comment: Interesting, I was using the preview edition on one my computers and it had the issue which lead me down this rabbit hole